# Can we use etags to get the latest version of image from a CDN

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront, akamai

We have a use case where we are storing our images in a CDN. Let's say we are storing a.jpg in the cache and if the user uploads a newer version of the file, then it will flush the cache and overwrite the a.jpg. Now the challenge is that the browser might have cached the file. Since we cannot flush the cached image in the browser we are thinking of using one of the 2 approaches mentioned below :

1. Append a version a_v1.jpg, a_v2.jpg (version id is the checksum) this will eliminate the need for flushing the browser and CDN cache. I found a lot of documentation about this on the internet and so many people are using this.
2. Use the etag of the file to find eliminate the stale cache in the browser. I found that CDN's support etags but I did not find literature that etag is used for images.

Can you please share your thoughts about using etag header for cache busting ? Is this a good practice to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

well i wouldn't suggest etag. This might have its advantage but has its setbacks as well. Say you are running two servers then the etag when content served from each of these servers might change.

Best thing i would suggest is control what the browser is caching and how long.
What i mean is send expiry headers when sending response from cdn to client browser say 5min TTL. This way browser will respect the expiry header. And once expired browser will send a fresh request to cdn when the page is refreshed.